# I can't update/animate my d3v5 scatterplot with transitions

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

As shown in fig 1, I have a scatterplot with a group element which consists of two things: a circle and text within.

### Figure1: My scatterplot

[image: Figure 1: My scatterplot]

The problem I'm facing is when I trying to animate this chart with new updated values. So, the following code describes the group element that I'm using to create the circles and add the text into it.

```
            var circlegrp = svg.append("g");

            var dot = circlegrp.append("g")
                .attr("class", "dots")
                .selectAll(".dot")
                .data(interpolateData(1800))
                .enter().append("circle")
                .attr("class", "dot")
                .style("fill", function (d) { return colorScale(color(d)); })
                .call(position);

            function position(dot) {
                dot.attr("cx", function (d) { return xScale(x(d)); })
                    .attr("cy", function (d) { return yScale(y(d)); })
                    .attr("r", 15)
                    .style("stroke", "black")
            }

            circlegrp.selectAll("dots")
                .data(interpolateData(1800))
                .enter().append("text")
                .attr("x", function (d) { return xScale((x(d))); })
                .attr("y", function (d) { return yScale(y(d)); })
                .text(function (d) { return countryCode(d); })
                .attr('dy', 3)
                .style("font-family", "Verdana")
                .style("text-transform", "uppercase")
                .style("font-size", "11px")
                .style("font-color", "green")
                .style("font-weight", "600")
                .style("font-style", "italic")
                .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
                .style('alignment-baseline', 'middle');
```

The interpolateData and interpolateValues functions used are as follows:

```
        function interpolateData(year) {
            return data.map(function (d) {
                return {
                    name: d.name,
                    region: d.region,
                    code: d.code,
                    income: interpolateValues(d.income, year),
                    lifeExpectancy: interpolateValues(d.lifeExpectancy, year),
                    childrenPerWoman: interpolateValues(d.childrenPerWoman, year),
                    population: interpolateValues(d.population, year)
                };
            });
         }

        function interpolateValues(values, year) {
            if (values.length == 0) {
                return -999.12345;
            }
            for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                if (values[i][0] == year) {
                    return values[i][1]
                }
                else if (i === values.length - 1) {
                    return -999.12345;
                }
            }
```

The data is the following format:

```
[
{"name": "Afghanistan", 
  "region": "South Asia", 
  "code": "afg", 
  "income": [[1800, 600], [1801, 601], ... ,[2100, 1200]],
  "population": [[1800, 122222], [1801, 60233231], ... ,[2100, 120232320]]
},
{"name": "India", 
  "region": "South Asia", 
  "code": "ind", 
  "income": [[1800, 1600], [1801, 6021], ... ,[2100, 11200]],
  "population": [[1800, 122222], [1801, 60233231], ... ,[2100, 120232320]]
},
... 195 more countries
]
```

From what I understand, I take the group which has the circles and the text and perform a transition over it. Is there any mistake here that I'm not seeing? From what I've been able to gather, I thought the following code snippet would work for me.

```
            circlegrp.selectAll()
                     .transition()
                     .duration(30000)
                     .tween("year", tweenYear);
            function tweenYear() {
                var year = d3.interpolateNumber(1800, 2020);
                return function (t) { displayYear(year(t)); };
            }

            // Updates the display to show the specified year.
            function displayYear(year) {
                dot.data(interpolateData(year), key).call(position);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`year` is not a valid attribute. Use `attr.cx` and `attr.cy` instead. You can even  decouple the year logic from this and have, for example, a slider. Then increase the year every 2 seconds and follow that up by a linear transition that also takes 2 seconds:

```js
const width = 600,
  height = 300;
const data = {};
d3.range(20).forEach(i => {
  data[2000 + i] = i ** 2;
});

const x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([2000, 2019])
  .range([0, width]);

const y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 361])
  .range([height, 0]);

const circle = d3.select("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("circle")
  .datum(data)
  .attr('r', 10)
  .attr("cx", x(2000))
  .attr("cy", d => y(d[2000]));

const slider = d3.select("input")
  .on("change", function() {
    console.log(this.value);
    transition(+this.value, 500);
  });

function transition(year, duration) {
  return circle
    .transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .ease(d3.easeLinear)
    .attr("cx", x(year))
    .attr("cy", d => y(d[year]));
}

function traverse(year, duration) {
  if (year > x.domain()[1]) {
    return;
  }
  transition(year, duration).on("end", () => {
    slider.attr("value", function() {
      return (+this.value) + 1;
    });
    traverse(year + 1, duration);
  });
}

traverse(2000, 500);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
<input type="range" min="2000" max="2019" step="1" value="2000" />
```